# MySQL - Join on proceedure result - recommendations on what I should do?

Tags: mysql

I have already read that this CANNOT be done. I'm looking for an alternative.

**Short problem**
I have a really long SQL query (with a union) and I want to use it like a view (hide the union and pretend it's a table) so I can join on it. Of course, you cannot pass parameters to views, nor can you join on the result of a stored procedure.

**Distilled essence of problem:**
I have `container`s

- `ContainerId` - uint, auto-increment
- `Parent` - uint, may be null, is a root container if not null
- `RootContainer` - uint, may be null (implies is root)
- `Location` - uint, may be null, only roots may have not null values.

I also have `item`s

- `ItemId` - uint, auto-increment
- `ContainedIn` - uint, may be null
- `Location` - uint, may be null (if not null, then `ContainedIn` must be null)

The query I want to hide is a union with 2 parts:
 The first part is all the items in a given location (with columns defined to be values that imply these items are in a container with ID0 named the location name)

These are then unioned with all the containers in the given location (which through joins contain all the items in those containers)

So I get a large list of items (with some container info too) - I then want to process these items.

```
    SELECT
      0 AS `ContainerId`,
      NULL AS `ParentContainer`,
      NULL AS `RootContainer`,
      (SELECT `Name` FROM LocationList WHERE LocationId=1) AS `ConName`,
      ITEM.*
    FROM ItemList ITEM

    WHERE
      ITEM.CurrentLocation=1
      AND
      1=1 #WHATEVER

UNION
    SELECT
      CON.ContainerId, 
      IF(CON.ParentContainer IS NULL,0,CON.ParentContainer) AS `ParentContainer`,
      IF(CON.`RootContainer` IS NULL, 0, CON.RootContainer) AS `RootContainer`,
      CON.Name AS `ConName`,
      ITEM.*
    FROM ContainerList CON
      LEFT JOIN ItemList ITEM ON(ITEM.ContainedIn = CON.ContainerId)
    WHERE
      CON.CurrentLocation = 1
      OR
      CON.RootContainer = ANY(
            SELECT ContainerId FROM ContainerList WHERE CurrentLocation=1)
```

This query did work, it's a chopped down version of the actual one I want to hide.

As you can see I create a 'fake' root node of id 0 which has the name of the location, I parent root containers to this node.

The type is unsigned, so I was lucky to have a 0, I cannot have an id for each location Id (I could use `CONCAT` and some magic to do this, but I risk the optimiser not following along)

I'm not sure what I should do to go ahead. My options are:

- Repeat myself a lot
- Write a view which has an extra column of the form `LocationId:ContainerId` - this way I can still derive from our generic tree data reader. I risk the optimiser not following along properly.
- Create 2 views and union the result

I've read this a few times, I hope it actually does make sense. I know 'what should I do' questions are quite soft; I doubt I'm the first to encounter this problem, so I ask what others have done.

Comment: If you could use a VIEW, what "parameters" would you like to pass to it?

Comment: The `LocationId` to act as the 0th container @RickJames (notice the select in the column for the first part of the union)

Comment: So, you want to logically build a resultset of all the containers (including #0), then throw away all but the one asked for?  I suspect views are not smart enough to optimize such.  Write it, then do `EXPLAIN SELECT ...;`.

Comment: @RickJames there is no container `0` - container `0` is a fictional container we populate with the id 0 and the name of the location (so everything appears inside the container [location name])